# Error. when trying to catch values from a arry list. and pass it to afunction to diplay markers on the map. Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I get a error,when i try to catch latitude and longitude from the array list and pass it to function  called displaymarkers() in Viewmap.java file.

i have added my code and the error . can any one help me to fix this error please.

**database handler (Dbhandler.java) class**

```
    package lk.adspace.jaffnatemples;



    import java.util.ArrayList;


    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class Dbhandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper  {


        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        // Database Name
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "jaffnatempletest";

        // Temple table name
        private static final String TABLE_TEMPLE = "templ";


        // Contacts Table Columns names
        private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
        private static final String KEY_TMPNAME = "temple_name";
        private static final String KEY_TMPTYPE = "temple_type";
        private static final String KEY_LATITUDE = "latitude";
        private static final String KEY_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
        private static final String KEY_IMGNAME = "image_name";
        private static final String KEY_YEARBUILD = "year_build";
        private static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
        private static final String KEY_CITY = "city";
        private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
        private static final String KEY_WEB = "website";
        private static final String KEY_TEL1 = "telephone1";
        private static final String KEY_TEL2 = "telephone2";
        private static final String KEY_DESCRI = "Description";
        private final ArrayList<kovil> temple_list = new ArrayList<kovil>();


        public Dbhandler (Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }



        // Creating Tables
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TEMPLE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TEMPLE + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL," + KEY_TMPNAME + " TEXT," + KEY_TMPTYPE + " TEXT," + KEY_LATITUDE + " TEXT," + KEY_LONGITUDE + " TEXT," + KEY_IMGNAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_YEARBUILD + " TEXT," + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT," + KEY_CITY + " TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT," + KEY_WEB + " TEXT," + KEY_TEL1 + " TEXT," + KEY_TEL2 + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_DESCRI + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TEMPLE_TABLE);
        }


        // Upgrading database
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TEMPLE);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
        }



        // Adding new temple
        public void Add_Temple(kovil Kovil) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_TMPNAME, Kovil.gettemplename()); 
        values.put(KEY_TMPTYPE, Kovil.gettempletype()); 
        values.put(KEY_LATITUDE, Kovil.getlatitude()); 
        values.put(KEY_LONGITUDE, Kovil.getlongitude()); 
        values.put(KEY_IMGNAME, Kovil.getimage_name()); 
        values.put(KEY_YEARBUILD, Kovil.getyear_build()); 
        values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, Kovil.getaddress()); 
        values.put(KEY_CITY, Kovil.getcity()); 
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, Kovil.getemail()); 
        values.put(KEY_WEB, Kovil.getwebsite()); 
        values.put(KEY_TEL1, Kovil.gettelephone1()); 
        values.put(KEY_TEL2, Kovil.gettelephone2());
        values.put(KEY_DESCRI, Kovil.getDescription());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_TEMPLE, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
        }






        // Getting single contact
        kovil Get_Temple(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_TEMPLE, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                KEY_TMPNAME, KEY_TMPTYPE, KEY_LATITUDE, KEY_LONGITUDE, KEY_IMGNAME, KEY_YEARBUILD, KEY_ADDRESS, KEY_CITY, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_WEB, KEY_TEL1, KEY_TEL2, KEY_DESCRI }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        kovil Kovil = new kovil(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8), cursor.getString(9), cursor.getString(10), cursor.getString(11), cursor.getString(12), cursor.getString(13));
        // return contact
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return Kovil;
        }





        // Getting All Contacts
        public ArrayList<kovil> Get_Temple(String temple_type, int Limit) {
        try {
            temple_list.clear();

            // Select All Query
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TEMPLE +" WHERE temple_type= " + temple_type +" LIMIT " + Limit;

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            System.out.print("CALLED");
            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                kovil Kovil = new kovil();
                Kovil.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                Kovil.settemplename(cursor.getString(1)); 
                Kovil.settempletype(cursor.getString(2)); 
                Kovil.setlatitude(cursor.getString(3)); 
                Kovil.setlongitude(cursor.getString(4)); 
                Kovil.setimage_name(cursor.getString(5)); 
                Kovil.setyear_build(cursor.getString(6)); 
                Kovil.setaddress(cursor.getString(7)); 
                Kovil.setcity(cursor.getString(8)); 
                Kovil.setemail(cursor.getString(9)); 
                Kovil.setwebsite(cursor.getString(10)); 
                Kovil.settelephone1(cursor.getString(11)); 
                Kovil.settelephone2(cursor.getString(12));
                Kovil.setDescription(cursor.getString(13));

                // Adding contact to list
                temple_list.add(Kovil);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            // return contact list
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
            return temple_list;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("all_temples", "" + e);
        }

        return temple_list;
        }



        public String collect(String temptype, String limit){

            SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
            String result="";
            String []column =new String[]{KEY_ID,KEY_TMPNAME,KEY_TMPTYPE,KEY_LATITUDE,KEY_LONGITUDE,KEY_IMGNAME,KEY_YEARBUILD,KEY_ADDRESS,KEY_CITY,KEY_EMAIL,KEY_WEB,KEY_TEL1,KEY_TEL2,KEY_DESCRI};
            Cursor c=ourDatabase.query("templ", column, null, null, null, null,null, limit);


            c.moveToFirst();
            int iKEY_ID = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID);
            int iKEY_TMPNAME= c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TMPNAME);
            int iKEY_TMPTYPE= c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TMPTYPE);

            for (c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){

                if (c.getString(iKEY_TMPTYPE).equals(temptype)){

            result = result+c.getString(iKEY_ID)+"\t\t"+c.getString(iKEY_TMPNAME)+"\t\t"+c.getString(iKEY_TMPTYPE)+"\n";
                }
            }

            return result;

        }




        // Getting contacts Count
        public int Get_Total_Temple() {
            String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TEMPLE;
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
            int count = cursor.getCount();
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
            return count;
        }


    }
```

**My Kovil. Java class**

```
    package lk.adspace.jaffnatemples;






    public class kovil {

        //public variables
        public int _id;
        public String _temple_name;
        public String _temple_type;
        public String _latitude;
        public String _longitude;
        public String _image_name;
        public String _year_build;
        public String _address;
        public String _city;
        public String _email;
        public String _website;
        public String _telephone1;
        public String _telephone2;
        public String _Description;
        public Object temple_name;

        //empty constructor
        public kovil (){

        }


        // int id, String temple_name, String temple_type, String latitude,  String longitude, String image_name, String year_build, String address, String city, String email, String website, String telephone1, String telephone2,  String Description


        public kovil(int id, String temple_name, String temple_type, String latitude,  String longitude, String image_name, String year_build, String address, 
                String city, String email, String website, String telephone1, String telephone2,  String Description) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub



              this._id= id;
              this._temple_name=temple_name;
              this._temple_type=temple_type;
              this._latitude=latitude;
              this._longitude=longitude;
              this._image_name=image_name;
              this._year_build=year_build;
              this._address=address;
              this._city=city;
              this._email=email;
              this._website=website;
              this._telephone1=telephone1;
              this._telephone2=telephone2;
              this._Description=Description;

        }



        public kovil(String temple_name, String temple_type, String latitude,  String longitude, String image_name, String year_build, String address, 
                String city, String email, String website, String telephone1, String telephone2,  String Description) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

              this._temple_name=temple_name;
              this._temple_type=temple_type;
              this._latitude=latitude;
              this._longitude=longitude;
              this._image_name=image_name;
              this._year_build=year_build;
              this._address=address;
              this._city=city;
              this._email=email;
              this._website=website;
              this._telephone1=telephone1;
              this._telephone2=telephone2;
              this._Description=Description;

        }


                public int getID() {
                return this._id;
                }


                public void setID(int id) {
                this._id = id;
                }


                public String gettemplename() {
                return this._temple_name;
                }


                public void settemplename(String temple_name) {
                this._temple_name=temple_name;
                }

                public String gettempletype() {
                return this._temple_type;
                }


                public void settempletype(String temple_type) {
                this._temple_type=temple_type;
                }

                public String getlatitude() {
                return this._latitude;
                }


                public void setlatitude(String latitude) {
                    this._latitude=latitude;
                }

                public String getlongitude() {
                return this._longitude;
                }


                public void setlongitude(String longitude) {
                    this._longitude=longitude;
                }


                public String getimage_name() {
                return this._image_name;
                }


                public void setimage_name(String image_name) {
                    this._image_name=image_name;
                }

                public String getyear_build() {
                return this._year_build;
                }


                public void setyear_build(String year_build) {
                    this._year_build=year_build;
                }


                public String getaddress() {
                return this._address;
                }


                public void setaddress(String address) {
                    this._address=address;
                }

                public String getcity() {
                return this._city;
                }


                public void setcity(String city) {
                    this._city=city;
                }


                public String getemail() {
                return this._email;
                }


                public void setemail(String email) {
                    this._email=email;
                }


                public String getwebsite() {
                return this._website;
                }


                public void setwebsite(String website) {
                    this._website=website;
                }


                public String gettelephone1() {
                return this._telephone1;
                }


                public void settelephone1(String telephone1) {
                    this._telephone1=telephone1;
                }

                public String gettelephone2() {
                return this._telephone2;
                }


                public void settelephone2(String telephone2) {
                    this._telephone2=telephone2;
                }


                public String getDescription() {
                return this._Description;
                }


                public void setDescription(String Description) {
                    this._Description=Description;
                }


    }
```

View map.java file

```
    package lk.adspace.jaffnatemples;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
    import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Circle;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptions;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polygon;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolygonOptions;

    public class Viewmap extends FragmentActivity implements 
    GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

        private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
        GoogleMap mMap;


        private static final double SEATTLE_LAT = 9.663216, SEATTLE_LNG =80.01333;
        private static final float DEFAULTZOOM = 15;


        LocationClient mLocationClient;
        ArrayList<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
        static final int POLYGON_POINTS = 4;
        Polygon shape;

        Dbhandler dbhand = new Dbhandler(this); 
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            if (servicesOK()) {
                setContentView(R.layout.view_map);

                if (initMap()) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    gotoLocation(SEATTLE_LAT, SEATTLE_LNG, DEFAULTZOOM);


                    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(SEATTLE_LAT, SEATTLE_LNG)).title("Jaffna Clock Tower");

                    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));
                    mMap.addMarker(marker);


                    ArrayList<kovil> object = dbhand.Get_Temple((getIntent().getExtras().getString("temple_type")), Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getExtras().getString("notemples")));


                    for (int i=0; i< Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getExtras().getString("notemples"));i++) {

                                kovil object2 = dbhand.Get_Temple(i);

                                String tempname = object2.gettemplename();
                                double latitude = Double.parseDouble(object2.getlatitude());
                                double longitude = Double.parseDouble(object2.getlongitude());
                                displaymarkers(latitude,longitude, tempname);
                    }



    //              
    //              displaymarkers(9.662502, 80.010239, "mugan kovil");
    //              displaymarkers(9.662502, 80.010239, "mugan kovil");
    //              displaymarkers(9.670931, 80.013201, "mugan kovil");




                        mMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
                        .add(new LatLng(9.662502, 80.010239), new LatLng(9.662502, 80.010239), new LatLng(9.670931, 80.013201), new LatLng(9.663216, 80.01333))
                        //.addHole(new LatLng(1, 1), new LatLng(1, 2), new LatLng(2, 2), new LatLng(2, 1), new LatLng(1, 1))
                       .fillColor(Color.GRAY));






                        int radius = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getExtras().getString("distance"));

                        drawcircle(radius);


                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Map not available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            else {
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
            }



        }


        public void drawcircle(int rad){

            int value = rad*1000;

             Circle circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
             .center(new LatLng(9.663216, 80.01333))
             .radius(value)
             .strokeColor(Color.RED)
             .fillColor(Color.WHITE));  
        }



        public boolean displaymarkers(double lati, double longi, String templename){

            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lati, longi)).title(templename);
            marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon));
            //marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            mMap.addMarker(marker);


            return true;
        }





        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public boolean servicesOK() {
            int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

            if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                return true;
            }
            else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
                Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
                dialog.show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to Google Play services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return false;
        }

        private boolean initMap() {
            if (mMap == null) {
                SupportMapFragment mapFrag =
                        (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                mMap = mapFrag.getMap();
            }
            return (mMap != null);
        }

        private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng,
                float zoom) {
            LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
            mMap.moveCamera(update);
        }




        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }




        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }




        @Override
        public void onDisconnected() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }






    }
```

**Error stack**

```
02-12 14:53:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(979): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 14:53:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(979): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{lk.adspace.jaffnatemples/lk.adspace.jaffnatemples.Viewmap}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
02-12 14:53:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2343)
02-12 14:53:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
02-12 14:53:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
02-12 14:53:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
02-12 14:53:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
02-12 14:53:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
02-12 14:53:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
02-12 14:53:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 14:53:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-12 14:53:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
02-12 14:53:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
02-12 14:53:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-12 14:53:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(979): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
02-12 14:53:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at     android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
02-12 14:53:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
02-12 14:53:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
02-12 14:53:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at lk.adspace.jaffnatemples.Dbhandler.Get_Temple(Dbhandler.java:114)
02-12 14:53:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at lk.adspace.jaffnatemples.Viewmap.onCreate(Viewmap.java:71)
02-12 14:53:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
02-12 14:53:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
02-12 14:53:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
02-12 14:53:34.554: E/AndroidRuntime(979):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: what is line 114 in DbHandler

Comment: Here is your error: `Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0` Have you tried fixing it or you ask for both finding it, and fixing it for you?

Comment: at which line you got error?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dbhandler dbhand = new Dbhandler(this);
```

..in ViewMap.java should be inside onCreate()

In DbHandler, Check if your cursor is getting populated at:

`kovil Kovil = new kovil(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),`...

Also, instead of kovil, i think you should be adding/populating the templelist variable

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the log, your problem seems that you try to get the first element in a list(index 0) and your list is empty(the size is 0)

`cursor.getString(0)` that seems to be the problem. your cursor has no records